# How to scrape from web all children of an attribute with one class?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to get the highlighted area (in the screenshot) in the website using BeautifulSoup4, but I cannot get what I want. Maybe you have a recommendation doing it with another way.

[Screenshot of the website I need to get data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sWov.jpg)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip
import urllib
import csv
import html5lib

urls = ['https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=1',
        'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=2'
        ]

# scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    content = soup.findAll("input", class_="casedetail filled")
    print(content)
```

My expected output is like this:

```
Ətraflı məlumat: 

İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib 
Xəyalə Cəmilova - sədrlik edən hakim
İlham Kərimli - tərkib üzvü
İsmayıl Xəlilov - tərkib üzvü

Tərəflər 
Cavabdeh: MAHMUDOV MAQSUD SOLTAN OĞLU
Cavabdeh: MAHMUDOV MAHMUD SOLTAN OĞLU
İddiaçı: QƏHRƏMANOVA AYNA NUĞAY QIZI

İşin mahiyyəti
Mənzil mübahisələri - Mənzildən çıxarılma
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it this way. Extracting the id that needs to be put in GET request for detailed info

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ['https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=1','https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=2']

def get_soup(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        soup = get_soup(url)
        detail_urls = [f'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/CaseDetail?caseId={i["value"]}' for i in soup.select('.caseId')]

        for next_url in detail_urls:
            soup = get_soup(next_url)
            data = [string for string in soup.select_one('[colspan="4"]').stripped_strings]
            print(data)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is there a way to extract this output to the csv file?

Comment: depends how you want it to look. The lists are variable length so it depends if you want one list item per column and don't mind jagged output.

Comment: Is it possible to make unique columns for all output? Because outputs have a standard model only informations changes

Comment: what is the standard model? They don't always have the same number of items. The range is 12-20

Comment: ['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Elnur Həsənov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'SEYİDOV VƏLİ MİRHƏŞİM', 'Cavabdeh:', '“SOCAR PETROLEUM” QAPALI SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'İddiaçı:', '"GREENROOM" MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Borc müqaviləsi üzrə mübahisələr']
the words with ":" sign are headlines and they are not changing

Comment: i have posted question like that if you are available to make it work i would appreciated

Comment: can you please look this question, in that question using http post request to get datas, there is no answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218685/using-http-request-get-output-of-each-manually-search-automatically

Answer (score 2):

Using the base url first get all the `caseid` and then pass those caseid to target url and then get the value of the first td tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urls = ['https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=1',
        'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=2'
        ]

target_url="https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/CaseDetail?caseId={}"

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for caseid in soup.select('input.casedetail'):
        #print(caseid['value'])
        soup1=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(target_url.format(caseid['value'])).content,'html.parser')
        print(soup1.select_one("td").text)
```

Comment: thanks but it is not precisely what i want. it returns:
Ətraflı məlumat:

İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib

    Xəyalə Cəmilova - sədrlik edən hakim
but i need to get 
Ətraflı məlumat: 

İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib 
Xəyalə Cəmilova - sədrlik edən hakim
İlham Kərimli - tərkib üzvü
İsmayıl Xəlilov - tərkib üzvü

Tərəflər 
Cavabdeh: MAHMUDOV MAQSUD SOLTAN OĞLU
Cavabdeh: MAHMUDOV MAHMUD SOLTAN OĞLU
İddiaçı: QƏHRƏMANOVA AYNA NUĞAY QIZI

İşin mahiyyəti
Mənzil mübahisələri - Mənzildən çıxarılma

Comment: can we get all the items?

Comment: Provide your expected output to your original post?

Comment: Yes you can.Give me sometime I am outside now?

Comment: i add it, there is lots of items there. your answer allows to get its first part but not he remained part

Comment: @ValiValizada : Check the updated answer.Copy and paste entire code and let me know the status.Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works great, how can i create a csv file with this output

Comment: @ValiValizada : You can use pandas for that.however for that you need to decide how your csv file should look like.

Comment: If you could post a new question and your csv requirements that would be great.

Comment: i have posted it

Comment: can you please look this question, in that question using http post request to get datas, there is no answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218685/using-http-request-get-output-of-each-manually-search-automatically